# Automysqlbackup not working with 16.04 Xubuntu when mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password'

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, mysql

### Intro

I installed automysqlbackup via the apt packager manager via `sudo apt install automysqlbackup`.

### Issue

`sudo automysqlbackup` worked fine with 14.04 but starting with 16.04, it doesn't work anymore once in mysql I do `update mysql.user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';` with Error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

### Question

Since `update mysql.user set plugin='unix_socket' where user='root';` will work with `sudo automysqlbackup`, I created a new config file (automysqlbackup.conf) in hope that by specifiying a config file with needed entries I can amend this issue. But running `sudo automysqlbackup /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf` still outputs the same error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. As a result, somehow `sudo automyslbackup` doesn't seem to take the config file into account. Do you guys have any clue why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`automysqlbackup` is a script, you can take a look at the code.

If you have installed it, open it with

```
sudo nano /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup
```

Here you will find at ~ line 106 an **options documa(e)ntation**.

In Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 it reads the configuration from `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` if it exists. I don't think it takes any command-line arguments.

In my case, I had to set the USERNAME and PASSWORD variables in the `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`. I also had to change the DBNAMES line. I removed the `--defaults-file` parameter and added the `--user=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD}`.

Comment: If you have a .my.cnf in the root directory, you can set it like this (to avoid hardcoding it):
PASSWORD=`grep password /root/.my.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`